# Hide some UITableViewCells when editing?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

**Background**

I'm really struggling to work out how to handle editing mode of a UITableView and hide some rows in when editing commences.

I'm using a grouped table view style with multiple sections and multiple rows per section. The last row of each section is titled "Add new...".

The idea is to allow the end user to click the "Add new..." row within each section and then be taken to a new screen where they fill in some fields and then are returned to that tableview with their new row added within the relevant section. So the last row does not really relate to the datasource and is more of a UX thing.

I've managed to get the Add row appended to the end of each section.

**The problem**

I have a button that calls: `tableView setEditing:animated:` and this insets all the rows and adds a delete icon to the left of each row.

What I don't want to do is allow the user to delete the "Add new..." row. So my orignal thinking was to just remove the delete capability for those "Add new..." rows using the `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:`.

This worked but looks really crap as all the rows are inset apart from the "Add new..." rows.

[image]

So my current thinking is when edit mode commences just remove the "Add" rows from the table view and then when editing mode finishes add them back again.

I tried to do this by traversing all the rows when the user clicked the edit button but it seems you can only get rows that are currently visible using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

So I can remove the ones that are visible but as soon as the user scrolls down the tableview the add buttons are still there for the sections that were not visible (at the time editing was initialised).

**Help!**

Does anyone know how I can just hide the "Add" rows from each section when the user edits the table and then add them back after?

I'm looking for the same functionality that the contacts app uses when the user edits a contact.

Comment: You should have a look into the Recipe sample code from Apple. They are doing the opposite. They are inserting row in editing mode. The code should give you an idea what you can do.

Comment: Really helpful answer. The sample code seems to do exactly what I'm attempting. I'm going to study it and see if it solves my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you did already close the answer, just use the method cellForRowAtIndexPath to pick up the cell you want to hide, and set its hidden property to YES. You make it!

---

Oh, I am sorry that I had not noticed you are using the group style, so my suggestion is that you can try to separate the add button to the others, like include it in a single section.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a green (+) button on the "Add line" row so it lines up with the deletable rows.

Simply override `-tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view delegate and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert` for that row.

Comment: Thanks, I knew you could do this but this is not what I want. I just wanted to know how to remove the "Add" row when editing. I have a specific need for this interface.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the Add line(s) from the actual data source and just calling [tableView reloadData] then when edit mode changes back, add them back into the data source and reloadData again.

Answer (score 0):

return YES from canEditCellAtIndexPath for every cell in the section then in override 
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {} and return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone for the "add line" row else return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete